# Move node $links to a sidebar

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

How can I print a nodes $links in a sidebar? What function can I call to retrieve them from outside the node.tpl.php and print them? I am still on the node. Also, I can't use Panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`template_preprocess_node`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess_node/6) function:

```
$variables['links'] = !empty($node->links) ? theme('links', $node->links, array('class' => 'links inline')) : '';
```

You may want to alter the theme function a bit for your use case. I haven't tested how this works with other modules, but if they use the node object instead to add their links it should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I will try this. The tricky part is I need to split some links out of the $links, and leave others below the node (Read more, comment, etc)

Comment: You can use hook_link_alter() to conditionally hide links. You could also use $links = module_invoke_all('link', 'node', $node, $conf['teaser']); modify the resulting array, and theme it yourself.